# Python 3:what is the best way to iterate for each value of a column?

Tags: python

I am new to Python and would like some advice on what is the simplest way for me to iterate on a given column of data.

My input file looks like this:

```
Col1,Col2,Col3<br/>
593457863416,959345934754,9456968345233455<br/>
487593748734,485834896965,4958558475345<br/>
694568245543,34857495345,494589589209<br/>
```

...

What I would like to do is add 100 to all items in column 2. So the output would like this:

```
Col1,Col2,Col3<br/>
593457863416,959345934854,9456968345233455<br/>
487593748734,485834897065‬,4958558475345<br/>
694568245543,34857495445,494589589209<br/>
```

...

Here is my code so far:

```
import csv

with open("C:/Users/r00t/Desktop/test/sample.txt") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    output_list = []
    for row in csv_reader:
        if line_count == 0:
            print(f'{", ".join(row)}')
            line_count += 1
        else:
            temp_list = []
            output_row = int(row[1])
            output_row = output_row + 100
            temp_list =[row[0], row[1], row[2]]
            output_list = [[row[0], output_row, row[2]]]
            print(output_list)
            line_count += 1
```

The code seems not optimal. Is there a way to not specify index for row? What happens when my file has more than 3 columns?

Thank you!
-r

Comment: It appears that you need to work through some introductory material on vectorized operations in a data frame (or other CSV-friendly representation).

Comment: Ravi, keep one thing in mind: the more you  write code the more you write bugs. Coding is about solution, so if you know you have a simple task, the must be a simple way to solve it. Said that, I wrote a answer bellow, take a look and also take a look at pandas. If you need any help feel confortable to dm me.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `csv.DictReader()`. Each row will now be in a dictionary, with keys being the column name, and the value being the row value.

Answer (score 0):

Here I have used pandas

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/r00t/Desktop/test/sample.txt')
# df1 = df+100
```

## edit-1

```py
df['col2'] = df['col2'] + 100
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html

Comment: Hi Dexter, actually Ravi wants to sum a value to a specific column. In your code you sum 100 to all columns. 
"What I would like to do is add 100 to all items in column 2" - Ravi

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion on how to do it. Use pandas which is very handy for dealing with data.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("sample.txt")
print(df)

# I am basicly getting all the rows of column index 1 (wich is the Col2)
df.iloc[:, 1] = df.iloc[:, 1] + 100
print(df)

# I could also use the column name
df["Col3"] = df["Col3"] + 1
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Series based value addition. Or you can use location or you can use it in place updation using pandas.

**Simplest Way(in pandas)**

```
df["column2"] = df["column2"] + 100
```

**ILocation(in pandas)**

```
df.iloc[:, 1] = df.iloc[:, 1] + 100
```

**Without Pandas**

```
file_read = csv.reader(open('/tmp/test.csv'))
file_data_in_list = list(file_read)
# Since now you have three columns,
# you can just simply go through 1st index and add 1 there 
for index in range(len(file_data_in_list):
    if index > 0:
        file_data_in_list[index][1] += 100 # Adds hundred to each line of 2nd column. 
# Now you can use file_data_in_list, it won't require you extra variables and the replacment is in place.
```

IT is better to use Column based Data Structure for this operations.